# filtering by columns (td) with angular for-each

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to generate an html table with three columns of names (this will end up being images, but anything works for an example). My data has multiple rows of people's names. I am dividing it into three columns for display. Regardless of what I've tried, the behavior I get is every name repeated three times, once per column.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="content" >
    <h2>In memory of those classmates who have passed on. Our thoughts are with their families and friends. Our memories are of those days when we were all together</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table-bordered">
        <tr ng-repeat="alumni in data.members | filter:alumni.columnNumber">
          <td alumni.columnNumber="1">{{alumni.firstName + ' ' + alumni.lastName}}</td>
          <td alumni.columnNumber="2">{{alumni.firstName + ' ' + alumni.lastName}}</td>
          <td alumni.columnNumber="3">{{alumni.firstName+ ' ' + alumni.lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Here is the angularJs controller code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

var vm = $scope;
vm.graduationYear = 1978;
vm.alumniInfo = {
alumniId: '',
firstName: '',
lastName: '',
columnNumber: '',
sortOrder: ''
};
vm.data = {
 "members" : [{
  "alumniId": 444,
  "firstName": "Fred",
  "lastName": "Flintstone",
  "columnNumber": 1,
  "sortOrder": 0
}, {
  "alumniId": 657,
  "firstName": "Barney",
  "lastName": "Rubble",
  "columnNumber": 1,
  "sortOrder": 0
}, {
  "alumniId": 647,
  "firstName": "Wile E",
  "lastName": "Coyote",
  "columnNumber": 2,
  "sortOrder": 0
}, {
  "alumniId": 655,
  "firstName": "Road",
  "lastName": "Runner",
  "columnNumber": 2,
  "sortOrder": 0
}, {
  "alumniId": 651,
  "firstName": "Bugs",
  "lastName": "Bunny",
  "columnNumber": 3,
  "sortOrder": 0
}, {
  "alumniId": 656,
  "firstName": "Quickstraw",
  "lastName": "McGraw",
  "columnNumber": 3,
  "sortOrder": 0
}]
}
});
```

Desired behavior would have Fred Flintstone and Barney Rubble in the first column of the table, Wiley Coyote and Roadrunner in the second column, and Bugs Bunny and Quickstraw McGraw in the third column. However, I'm getting each name in each of the three columns.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/eUQw248AGjMZsPo9uxid?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using tables, you could use CSS Columns to achieve something like this in a much more elegant manner. Here's the code to replace:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="column-count: 3">
    <div ng-repeat="alumni in data.members">
      {{ alumni.firstName + ' ' + alumni.lastName }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check out this plunker here for example: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/fFkdVbPxRkVp2wTy

Comment: Thank you. I don't have to do a lot of front-end work and I would've never come up with this solution. Brilliantly simple and works great.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for tables, which has pretty good features. You might have to modify the data format a little and you are good to go.

http://ng-table.com/#/